# Is it possible to keep a MySQL query from running awry and bringing down your site?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is it possible to configure MySQL so that it has some kind of execution limit similar to PHP's max execution time so that if a Query is taking longer than - say - 30 seconds, it automatically gets killed?

I just ran a poorly written query on phpMyAdmin as a test and it ate up all the CPU and killed my site for about 15 minutes...had to restart MySQL to bring my site back.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is probably better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Best advice would probably be pay more attention to the queries ran on your site.

Answer (score 0):

couple of options:

5.5.4. Setting Account Resource Limits (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html)

5.2.4. The Slow Query Log (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html)